# Curl command does not return the entire HTML source of Secure Webpage

Tags: javascript, html, curl

I tried to login and read the webpage using `curl` command on Unix, but it does did not return the entire HTML structure of a given URL of the webpage. It has returned few HTML content along with JavaScript portion only.

Please advise me further on it.

Command:

```
 curl --cookie cjar --cookie-jar cjar --data 'name=username' --data 
'pass=pwd' --data 'form-id=user_login' --data 'op=Log in' --location 
--output ~/tmp/login.html https://tableau-dev.swissre.com
/#/signin?disableAutoSignin=yes
```

Comment: It **does** return the entire HTML source. The modified DOM you get after executing the JavaScript is not part of the HTML source (and it requires that you execute the JavaScript to get it). If you want that, don't use cURL, use something that executes JavaScript.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise.